# Program goes into a continuous loop or does not continue running

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, button

The actual goal of the program is for me to guess the number that the program generates. The first thing it should ask me is whether I want to play. Next I have to enter how many attempts I want for this and then the window comes up in which I enter my number. The problem I have here is that this last window doesn't appear. I suspect that it is due to the "while" loop, but I don't know how to implement it otherwise.

```
`from tkinter import *
import random

def yes():

    window_2 = Tk()
    window_2.title("Zahlenraten")
    versuch = Entry(window_2, width=20)
    versuch.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
    
    def play(versuch = versuch):
        
        window_3 = Tk()
        window_3.title("Zahlenraten")
        eingabe = Entry(window_3, width=20)
        eingabe.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
        label3 = Label(window_3, text = "Meine Zahl liegt zwischen 1 und 50.")
        label3.grid(row = 1, columnspan = 2)
        label4 = Label(window_3, text = "Gib deine Zahl ein:")
        label4.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
        
        i=0
        x = random.randint(1,50) 
        aktiv = True
        while aktiv:
                
            def guess(eingabe = eingabe, versuch = versuch, i=i, x=x):
                label2 = Label(window_3, text = "Das ist dein Versuch: " + str(i+1)+" Die Zufallszahl lautet: " + str(x))
                label2.grid(row = 0, columnspan = 2)
                entry = float(eingabe.get())
                tries = float(versuch.get())
                
                if i == tries:
                    label3.config(text = "Du hast alle Versuche aufgebraucht!")
                    aktiv = False
                else:
                    if entry > x:
                        label3.config(text = "Deine Zahl ist zu groß.")
                    elif entry < x:
                        label3.config(text = "Deine Zahl ist zu klein.")
                    else:
                        label3.config(text = "Du hast gewonnen!")
                        aktiv = False

            i=i+1
            eingabe = Entry(window_3, width=20)
            eingabe.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
            button5 = Button(window_3, text="Confirm", command = guess).grid(row = 3)

        window_3.mainloop()

    button3 = Button(window_2, text="Confirm", command = play).grid(row = 1, column = 0)
    label1 = Label(window_2, text = "Wie viele Versuche möchtest du haben?").grid(row = 0, column = 0)
    window_2.mainloop()

def no():
    window_1 = Tk()
    window_1.title("Abbruch")
    label1 = Label(window_1, text = "Bist du dir sicher, dass du das Spiel abbrechen möchtest?").grid(row = 0, columnspan = 2)
    button3 = Button(window_1, text="Yes", command = window_1.quit).grid(row = 1, column = 0)
    button4 = Button(window_1, text ="No", command = yes).grid(row = 1, column = 1)

window = Tk()
window.title("Zahlenraten")
label = Label(window, text = "Do you want to play with me?").grid(row = 0, columnspan = 2)
button1 = Button(window, text="Yes", command = yes).grid(row = 1, column = 0)
button2 = Button(window, text ="No", command = no).grid(row = 1, column = 1)`
```

Comment: Variables that are assigned inside of a function are local to that function unless you explicitly say that they are global.  So inside the guess function, `aktiv` is a local variable.  It has no effect on the loop variable in the outer function.

Comment: Also, did you really intend `play()` and `guess()` to be defined as sub-functions inside another function?  That's an odd way to do things.